# React Native - ScrollView: How would one initialize the view at the bottom?

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I found resources on adjusting the view using refs, scrollTo, and the onContentSizeChange property of a ScrollView, but if I wanted the ScrollView to be mounted with the scroll position at the bottom how would I do that if possible?

The closest I can come is calling a scrollTo based on a ref on the componentDidMount method.  However, even with animated set to false it still visually scrolls to the bottom.